# Why when i put the right input the switch statement get ignored

Tags: c, visual-studio, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

OUTPUT:

```
Select your sign Tom:        [X]    or    [O]
Y
ERROR ENTER A DIFFERENT CHARACTER
X
Player 2 = O
```

But i want it like that:

```
Select your sign Tom:        [X]    or    [O]
Y
ERROR ENTER A DIFFERENT CHARACTER
X
Player 1 = X
Player 2 = O
```

```
printf("Select your sign %s:        [X]    or    [O]\n", PLAYER1);
        scanf(" %c", &P1_SIGN);

            do{
                switch (P1_SIGN) {          //entrata segni

                case 'X':
                    puts("Player 1 = X\n");
                    P1_SIGN = 'X';
                    break;

                case 'x':
                    puts("Player 1 = X\n");
                    P1_SIGN = 'X';
                    break;

                case 'O':
                    puts("Player 1 = O\n");
                    P1_SIGN = 'O';
                    break;

                case 'o':
                    puts("Player 1 = O\n");
                    P1_SIGN = 'O';
                    break;
                
                default:
                    puts("ERROR ENTER A DIFFERENT CHARACTER");
                    scanf(" %c", &P1_SIGN);
                    break;
                    
            }} while(P1_SIGN != 'X' && P1_SIGN != 'x' && P1_SIGN != 'O' && P1_SIGN != 'o');

            if (P1_SIGN == 'X' || P1_SIGN == 'x') {

                puts("Player 2 = O\n");
            } else {

                puts("Player 2 = X\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `scanf()`s in wrong positions.

The second `scanf()` will read the input `X` and it will make the condition of `do-while` loop false. Therefore, the loop body won't run again and therefore `Player 1 = X` isn't printed.

You should remove both of your `scanf()`s and instead of them add one `scanf()` inside the `do-while` loop, before the `switch` statement.

```
            do{
                scanf(" %c", &P1_SIGN); // put scanf() here
                switch (P1_SIGN) {          //entrata segni
```